# What does curpath stand for?

Tags: linux, posix

I'm reading [cd command's POSIX manual](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cd.html).
I've been guessing the 'curpath' in the manual stands for a current path or something, but It still remains unclear to me to understand the whole document.
Below is the description.

> In the following steps, the symbol **curpath** represents an intermediate value used to simplify the description of the algorithm used by `cd`. There is no requirement that **curpath** be made visible to the application.

The most unclear part of this description to me is, "intermediate value" Could anyone give me some examples about the "curpath" and "intermediate value"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [page](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cd.html) contains a description of the steps that a `cd` implementation should follow in order to be POSIX compliant. `curpath` is like a "temporary variable". Let's say that initially it is defined and assigned a dummy value. The following steps can modify its value, and finally `curpath` will hold the result of the processing. You can see at step 10, that finally there is a call to the system function `chdir()` with the argument `curpath`. Only this final value is required to be visible outside.

So, it is an intermediate value, not required to be visible to the application, means there is no need to know any temporary values of `curpath`, or even to have exactly these steps, this is a description of how an implementation should work. The requirement is that a program implementing the `cd` command, should give, for the whole input space, the same final result with what I get if I follow manually this algorithm.

---

Example, how to follow a unique input case:

- I am in the home directory (`PWD=/home/user`)  and I type `cd ..`
- step 1: condition is false, there is a *directory* (argument) provided.
- step 2: condition is false.
- step 3: condition is false, it doesn't start with slash.
- step 4: True, starts with dots, go to step 6.
- step 6: `curpath=..`
- step 7: It doesn't start with `/`, then `curpath=/home/user/..`
- step 8: etc until the end.

Noone outside any code block doing this, is required to see these temporary `curpath` values.

Comment: Thanks for the specific example! That's what I really want to get.